# Is it trivial that you cannot get apart 2 linked unknots?

Tags: knot-theory

I have read that: a trefoil is not an unknot is not trivial in knot theory. And it put the following question in me. Is it also not trivial that you cannot get apart 2 linked unknots? I mean, is it possible that many professional mathematicians cannot instantly prove the fact without theorems of knot theory?

Let me give some details.

Initially, the link shows exactly 2 crossings at most.

Comment: Sure, it is non trivial.

Comment: It's non-trivial as well, but I'd say it's easier to prove that (and more mathematicians would instantly come up with a proof that), the Hopf link (standard clasp of two round unknots) is linked, than that the trefoil is knotted, because one of the components is non-trivial in the homology of the complement of the other --- i.e. they have non-zero _linking number_. (But there are also linked unknots which are linked but not for this reason.)

Comment: (Continuing) That's maybe not really easier than various ways to prove the trefoil is knotted, but it's more familiar to most mathematicians, because it's a standard idea even outside of knot theory.